# Using sed to replace umlauts

Tags: shell, sed, special-characters, tex

I tried the following:

```
sed -e 's/ü/\\"u/g' filename.tex>filename2.tex
```

but my terminal doesn't recognise the umlaut, so replaces all `u` with `\"u`. I know that tex has packages and what-nots that might solve this problem, but I am interested in a **sed** way for the moment.

Comment: What encoding does your input file use? What encoding does your terminal use?

Comment: I didn't get what you want to have in the final replaced file. `"u` or `\"u` or simply `u` or what?

Comment: @Kent I want to replace the umlauted letters by their tex equivalents, so ü replaced by \"u.

Comment: what is the output of `echo $LANG` and what it gives you from `file file.tex`

Comment: @Kent `echo $LANG` returned an empty line in my shell. `file file.tex` gave me  _LaTeX document text_.

Comment: Maybe a bit unrelated but I was looking for a sed command which replaces ä with ae and so on and did not find it. So I wrote it and thought it might be useful to others: echo äÄöÖlüÜ | sed 's/ä/ae/g;s/Ä/Ae/;s/ö/oe/g;s/Ö/Oe/g;s/ü/ue/g;s/Ü/Ue/g;'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The fundamental problem is that there is a complex interaction between `sed`, your locale, your terminal, your shell, and the file you are operating on.  Here is a list of things to try.

- If you are lucky, your shell, `sed`, and the file you are working on have complete agreement on what the character you are trying to replace should be represented as.  In your case, you already tried that, and it failed.

  ```
  sed 's/ü/\\"u/g' filename.tex
  ```
- If you are only slightly less lucky, the other parts are fine, and it's just that your `sed` is not modern enough to grok the character sequence you are trying to replace.  A trivial `sed` script like yours can be simply passed to `perl` instead, which usually is more up to date when it comes to character encodings.

  ```
  perl -pe 's/ü/\\"u/g' filename.tex
  ```

  If the character encoding is UTF-8, you may need to pass a `-CSD` option to Perl, and/or express the character you wish to replace with an escape of some sort.  You can say `\xfc` for a raw hex code (that happens to be `ü` in Latin-1 and Latin-9) or `\x{00fc}` for a Unicode character, or even `\N{LATIN SMALL LETTER U WITH DIAERESIS}`; but notice that Unicode has several representations for this glyph (precomposed or decomposed, normalized or not).  See also http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html

  (For in-place editing, perhaps you want to add the `-i` option, too.)
- Finally, you may need to break down and simply figure out the raw bytes of the character code you want to replace.  A few lines of hex dump of the problematic file should be helpful. After that, Perl should be able to cope, but you need to figure out how to disable character set encoding and decoding etc.  If, say, you find out that the problematic sequence is `0xFF 0x03` then `perl -pe 's/\xff\x03/\\"u/g' filename.tex` should work.

Comment: When I copy and paste your perl suggestion into my shell, it removes the umlaut from the u. So again, it replaces all u not just the umlauted u. I suppose this means that the shell itself doesn't recognise the special charactors.

Comment: Seems likely, yes.  If the encoding is UTF-8 then the character would be represented as `\xc3\xbc`, try that?

Comment: I tried `perl -pe 's/\xc3/\xbc/g'` but it didn't seem to affect the document at all.

Comment: @choroba I set up a minimal document with the following: üäö and then did `sed -e 's/\xc3\xbc/\\"u/g' minimal.tex>minimal2.tex` for which the output in the created file is üäö. So no change!

Comment: @Geoff: What does `xxd minimal.tex` return? Or any other hexdump.

Comment: @choroba "should work" depends entirely on (a) your version of `sed` (adding platform information to the question would be pertinent) and (b) the encoding of the file.  We still don't know either.

Comment: @choroba I did `xxd` and I got `0000000: c3bc c3a4 c3b6                           ......` does this mean nything to you?

Comment: @tripleee I did `file minimal.tex` and got `minimal.tex: UTF-8 Unicode text, with no line terminators`

Comment: @Geoff: Yes. Then `perl -pe 's/\xc3\xbc/\\u/g'` should work for you.

Comment: ... except you want the replacement to be `\\"u` if I understand correctly.

Comment: @tripleee Bravo, you did it! So what excatly is \xc3 so I can find the codes of the other charactors?

Comment: http://fileformat.info/ is a good resource.  0xC3 is the first byte of the multi-byte UTF-8 encoding of U+00FC.  See e.g. http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fc/index.htm -- you'll find down there that 0xC3 0xBC is the UTF-8 sequence for this character.

Answer (score 1):

In case someone needs the other way round:

```
sed -i 's/\\"u/ü/g;s/\\"a/ä/g;s/\\"o/ö/g;s/\\"U/Ü/g;s/\\"A/Ä/g;s/\\"O/Ö/g;s/{\\ss}/ß/g' *.tex
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
sed -i 's/\([\ä\ö\ü\Ä\Ü\Ö]\)/\&\1uml\;/g;y/\ä\ö\ü\Ä\Ö\Ü/aouAOU/;s/\ß/\&szlig\;/g' ${FILE}
```

Comment: I tried, I failed! I got the following error message:  _transform strings are not the same length._

Comment: mhh...maybe sed -i 's/\ä/\&auml\;/g;s/\Ä/\&Auml\;/g;s/\ö/\&ouml\;/g;s/\Ö/\&Ouml\;/g;s/\ü/\&uuml\;/g;s/\Ü/\&Uuml\;/g;s/\ß/\&szlig\;/g' ${FILE}  works

Comment: The OP is looking for translating into TeX escapes, not HTML entities.